# Search Guard connect to remote Elasticsearch cluster using SSL

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl-certificate, elastic-stack

Used [this](https://gryzli.info/2018/12/01/elasticsearchelk-stack-security-howto/) guide for SSL certs creation

I'm trying to connect to remote Elasticsearch cluster. Both clusters are using SSL certificates (signed by same CA), is it possible ?

Local cluster:

```
cluster.name: client1
searchguard.enterprise_modules_enabled: false


node.name: ekl.test.com
node.master: true
node.data: true
node.ingest: true


network.host: 0.0.0.0

#http.host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: ["ekl1.test1.com","ekl.test.com"]



http.port: 9200


discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ekl.test.com", "ekl2.test2.com"]


discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

xpack.security.enabled: false


searchguard.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/node1.pem'
searchguard.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath: 'ssl/node1.key'
searchguard.ssl.transport.pemtrustedcas_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/root-ca.pem'
searchguard.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false
searchguard.ssl.transport.resolve_hostname: false
searchguard.ssl.http.enabled: true
searchguard.ssl.http.pemcert_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/node1_http.pem'
searchguard.ssl.http.pemkey_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/node1_http.key'
searchguard.ssl.http.pemtrustedcas_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/root-ca.pem'
searchguard.nodes_dn:
- CN=ekl.test.com,OU=Ops,O=BugBear BG\, Ltd.,DC=BugBear,DC=com
- CN=ekl1.test1.com,OU=Ops,O=BugBear BG\, Ltd.,DC=BugBear,DC=com
searchguard.authcz.admin_dn:
- CN=admin.test.com,OU=Ops,O=BugBear Com\, Inc.,DC=example,DC=com
```

Remote cluster:

```
cluster.name: client2
searchguard.enterprise_modules_enabled: false


node.name: ekl1.test.com
node.master: false
node.data: true
node.ingest: false


network.host: 0.0.0.0

#http.host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: ["ekl.test.com","ekl1.test1.com"]



http.port: 9200


discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ekl6.test1.com", "ekl1.test1.com"]


discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

xpack.security.enabled: false


searchguard.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/node2.pem'
searchguard.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath: 'ssl/node2.key'
searchguard.ssl.transport.pemtrustedcas_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/root-ca.pem'
searchguard.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false
searchguard.ssl.transport.resolve_hostname: false
searchguard.ssl.http.enabled: true
searchguard.ssl.http.pemcert_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/node2_http.pem'
searchguard.ssl.http.pemkey_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/node2_http.key'
searchguard.ssl.http.pemtrustedcas_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/root-ca.pem'
searchguard.nodes_dn:
- CN=ekl.test.com,OU=Ops,O=BugBear BG\, Ltd.,DC=BugBear,DC=com
- CN=ekl1.test1.com,OU=Ops,O=BugBear BG\, Ltd.,DC=BugBear,DC=com
searchguard.authcz.admin_dn:
- CN=admin.test.com,OU=Ops,O=BugBear Com\, Inc.,DC=example,DC=com
Certificates are self-signed
```

I can make curl to remote cluster from local one.

```
 curl -vX GET "https://admin:Pass@ekl1.test1.com:9200"
```

I added remote domain in Kibana GUI: ekl1.test1.com:9200

and getting this error in ES log:

> RemoteClusterConnection] [4P1fXFO] fetching nodes from external cluster >[client2] failed
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [][172.31.37.123:9200] >handshake_timeout[30s]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by specifying port 9300 instead 9200 in Kibana interface

and

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
```